# how to integrate an api in Odoo

Tags: api, odoo, tracking, odoo-8, odoo-9

I want to integrate order tracking services of any company like TSC,UPS,DHL etc Please give me some suggestion or minimal code.I'll be very thankful. I'm a beginner with Odoo so my question might seem stupid.

Comment: Give us more details, and post code that you tried so far.

Comment: For tracking you just need to integrate their api to python, that doesn't have direct connection to odoo

Comment: I need api please. Have you any link .

Answer (score 0):

For tracking you have to download their api/webservice and get the developer test key. for eg. for FedEx they have a web service you can download their wsdl file and do a soap request by [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation) in python, before doing that test it in [soapui](https://www.soapui.org/). Click [here](http://www.fedex.com/us/webservices/wsdldemo/index.html) for FedEx (usefull link). Chick [here](https://www.ups.com/media/en/UPS_dev_kit_user_guide.pdf) for UPS(useful link).

This will be a good enough to start you off.

Comment: look at the suds documentation try that with FedEx webservice.They have the code explained very well.